# Recursive Control Finder Returning TextBox as Literal

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I've been using this code for awhile where a form has multiple controls that a user fills out, e.g., text boxes, drop-downs, radio buttons, etc...and it recursively finds them all and then stores the resulting values in a XML document. However, I ran into a problem where the values in the database (stored as XML with each control as a separate node) were not complete. After doing some investigating I eliminated configuration issues with my XML templates and the database.

I then went ahead and attached a debugger to the IIS worker process and found that the recursive function is for some reason returning the control as System.Web.UI.LiteralControl and not as Sytem.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox like it has a million times in the past.

ASP.NET Form:

```
<div class="field">
                <label>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Text="*" ID="ValidateCompanyName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<%$ AppSettings: ValidateCompanyName %>"
                    ControlToValidate="ControlCompanyName" CssClass="requiredField" SetFocusOnError="True">
                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:Literal ID="ControlFieldCompanyName" runat="server" Text="<%$ AppSettings: FieldCompanyName %>" />
                </label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="ControlCompanyName" runat="server" CssClass="form" />
                <br>
            </div>
```

Recursive Control Function:

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
    if (root.ID == id)
        return root;

    foreach (Control ctl in root.Controls)
    {
        Control foundCtl = FindControlRecursive(ctl, id);

        if (foundCtl != null)
            return foundCtl;
    }

    return null;
}
```

I thought maybe there was an issue with it being the first form control so I put a hidden text box before the misbehaving control with some default text...still no go. Then I decided to change the name of the control to just "ControlCompany" and it began returning it as System.Web.UI.TextBox.

It has me stumped.

UPDATE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdtiX.png

UPDATE2: It has something to do with the masterpage. Removed the references from the form and changed the recursive function to only iterate over Page and not Page.Master.

```
FormToEmailHandler.ProcessForm(Page.Master, contactMethod, pageName, escapedEmailAddress, escapedContactName, true);
```

changed to:

```
FormToEmailHandler.ProcessForm(Page, contactMethod, pageName, escapedEmailAddress, escapedContactName, true);
```

and

```
public static XmlDataDocument ProcessForm(
    MasterPage master,
    string contactMethod,
    string pageName,
    string escapedEmail,
    string escapedName,
    bool processAll)
```

changed to:

```
public static XmlDataDocument ProcessForm(
    Page master,
    string contactMethod,
    string pageName,
    string escapedEmail,
    string escapedName,
    bool processAll)
```

UPDATE 3:

Here's the XML processing code just to show how it integrates with the recursive function.

```
public static XmlDataDocument ParseFormIntoXml(XmlDataDocument xmlTemplate, Control root)
{
    XmlNode nodeContact = xmlTemplate.SelectSingleNode("/Contact");
    if (nodeContact != null)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode thisNode in nodeContact.ChildNodes)
        {
            string controlToFind = thisNode.Name;

            switch (controlToFind)
            {
                case "DateTime":
                    thisNode.InnerText = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    break;
                case "ReferringLink":
                    thisNode.InnerText = CheckReferer(HttpContext.Current);
                    break;
                default:
                {
                    Control thisControl = FindControlRecursive(root, controlToFind);

                    if (thisControl != null)
                    {
                        string controlType = thisControl.GetType().ToString();

                        switch (controlType)
                        {
                            case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox":

                                var thisBox = (TextBox) thisControl;
                                thisNode.InnerText = thisBox.Text;

                                break;

                            case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList":

                                var thisList = (DropDownList) thisControl;
                                thisNode.InnerText = thisList.SelectedItem.Text;

                                break;

                            case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox":

                                var thisListBox = (ListBox) thisControl;
                                thisNode.InnerText = thisListBox.SelectedValue;

                                break;

                            case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList":

                                var thisRadioList = (RadioButtonList) thisControl;
                                thisNode.InnerText = thisRadioList.SelectedValue;

                                break;


                            case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList":

                                var thisCheckList = (CheckBoxList) thisControl;


                                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<hr/>");

                                foreach (
                                    ListItem thisCheckBox in
                                        thisCheckList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(
                                            thisCheckBox => thisCheckBox.Selected))
                                    thisNode.InnerText = string.Format(
                                        "{0}{1};", thisNode.InnerText, thisCheckBox.Value);

                                thisNode.InnerText = thisNode.InnerText.TrimEnd(';');

                                break;

                            case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField":

                                var thisHidden = (HiddenField) thisControl;
                                thisNode.InnerText = thisHidden.Value;

                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    return xmlTemplate;
}
```

UPDATE 4: Seems to be a build caching issue. James' code now works. Then I modified it not to work...and it still works.

Comment: Since you are looking for controls that have user input I suggest filtering your `ControlCollection` based on controls that implement the `IPostBackDataHandler` interface. This way it can never return a `Literal`, and possibly introduces a performance increase.

Comment: Thanks. I'm eventually going to rewrite this CMS application in the future using ASP.NET MVC, so I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my mistake earlier. My brain must not be functioning properly today.

First, your original recursive function should work fine. My apologies for being an idiot. Having a little more information now, the problem you're having could be related to one of a couple of things:

1. You're specifying the wrong root container when you call the function. Wherever the control lives (`Page`, `Master`) should be the root container you start searching in.
2. You mentioned that there might be a caching issue - this would make sense, and more than likely you've found the right solution already.

I think it would make sense to disable caching on this page, which you can do by adding the following to the page load event:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

You can also achieve this by adding the following meta tags to your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" CONTENT="0">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

This should ensure that the logic runs when it's supposed to. Once we know that the logic is running consistently, if you're still experiencing an issue, we need to look further into where the control lives vs. where you're searching for it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say file compilation. I had an issue yesterday with another page where it was referencing an older version from ASP.NET temporary storage cache. Rebuilding the solution fixed the problem.

Comment: Just for posterity, I created another page using FindControl instead of rolling my own recursive function. Shouldn't run into this again.